# Windows driver creation

Tags: windows, driver, trackpad

I would like to try creating a custom driver for a trackpad of mine. Could you please recommend an opensource driver to start with? My search turned out nothing, so I hope there actually any skeleton code to begin building from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a USB HID device? If so, it should be pretty easy to read data from the device.

Check out [this code (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/USB_HID.aspx) for example.

There is also the [UMDF (User Mode Driver Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463294) that supposedly allows writing drivers for USB-like devices in user mode. I have never used it though. There are a couple of [sample drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463290) to download.